# How to use Rpi cam with python and the command line

Tags: python, command-line, raspberry-pi, camera

My OS-Version (`cat /etc/os-release`):

```
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="11"
VERSION="11 (bullseye)"
VERSION_CODENAME=bullseye
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"
```

My Python Version (`python --version --version`):

```
Python 3.9.2 (default, Mar 12 2021, 04:06:34) 
[GCC 10.2.1 20210110]
```

Camera: Rpi cam v2 ir

Rpi: Rpi 4 model b 2gb ram

connected via 'camera' port on rpi.

I tried to take a picture with python AND the command line but ran into problems with `Legacy Camera`.

`sudo raspi-config>3 Interface Options>I1 Legacy Camera` is enabled. Now I run `raspistill -o test.jpg`. It works entirely fine and I get the wanted result as a file. Now I want to try that with python. My file `cam.py` contains the following:

```
import time
from picamera2 import Picamera2, Preview

print('imported all.')

picam = Picamera2()

print('Created object.')

config = picam.create_preview_configuration()
picam.configure(config)

picam.start_preview(Preview.QTGL)

picam.start()
time.sleep(2)
picam.capture_file("test.jpg")

picam.close()
```

The output is:

```
imported all.
[0:05:22.534750202] [1533]  INFO Camera camera_manager.cpp:297 libcamera v0.0.5+83-bde9b04f
Camera(s) not found (Do not forget to disable legacy camera with raspi-config).
Camera __init__ sequence did not complete.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera2/picamera2.py", line 242, in __init__
    self._open_camera()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera2/picamera2.py", line 442, in _open_camera
    if not self._initialize_camera():
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera2/picamera2.py", line 406, in _initialize_camera
    raise RuntimeError("Camera(s) not found (Do not forget to disable legacy camera with raspi-config).")
RuntimeError: Camera(s) not found (Do not forget to disable legacy camera with raspi-config).

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rapberrypi/Dokumente/Python/cam/main.py", line 6, in <module>
    picam = Picamera2()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera2/picamera2.py", line 254, in __init__
    raise RuntimeError("Camera __init__ sequence did not complete.")
RuntimeError: Camera __init__ sequence did not complete.
```

-> The code didn't work because the Picamera2() object couldn't be created.

If I run the same code with `sudo raspi-config>3 Interface Options>I1 Legacy Camera` disabled, it works and does what it should do. The output is:

```
imported all.
[0:01:41.300487614] [1506]  INFO Camera camera_manager.cpp:297 libcamera v0.0.5+83-bde9b04f
[0:01:41.333794109] [1509]  WARN RPI vc4.cpp:383 Mismatch between Unicam and CamHelper for embedded data usage!
[0:01:41.334778356] [1509]  INFO RPI vc4.cpp:437 Registered camera /base/soc/i2c0mux/i2c@1/imx219@10 to Unicam device /dev/media4 and ISP device /dev/media2
[0:01:41.334860484] [1509]  INFO RPI pipeline_base.cpp:1101 Using configuration file '/usr/share/libcamera/pipeline/rpi/vc4/rpi_apps.yaml'
Created object.
[0:01:41.343286973] [1506]  INFO Camera camera.cpp:1033 configuring streams: (0) 640x480-XBGR8888 (1) 640x480-SBGGR10_CSI2P
[0:01:41.343998316] [1509]  INFO RPI vc4.cpp:565 Sensor: /base/soc/i2c0mux/i2c@1/imx219@10 - Selected sensor format: 640x480-SBGGR10_1X10 - Selected unicam format: 640x480-pBAA
```

If I try to run `raspistill -o test.jpg` with Legacy Camera disabled, it reuturns `ERROR: the system should be configured for the legacy camera stack`.

Now my question is how to take pictures with both the command line and python without having to change the settings and rebooting the rpi every time. I also would be interested in an explanation on this error (`[0:01:41.333794109] [1509]  WARN RPI vc4.cpp:383 Mismatch between Unicam and CamHelper for embedded data usage!` (from running cam.py with with Legacy Camera disabled)) but that isn't crucial since it works regardless of the error.